# Iframe HTML tag refused to connect when src set from a function

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to find latitude and longitude using a function. Then use the values to set src in an Iframe to show position in Google map. But Google refused to connect. When the same 'src' set from the iframe it works. Both are the same, except the function generates src dynamically. Why it didn't work and how to make it work?

```
    </script>
         .....
            function showPosition(position){
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            long = position.coords.longitude;
            lin = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q="+lat+","+long+"&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed";
            fh.innerHTML = lin;
            document.getElementById('pmap').src = lin;
        }
    </script>
    
    <iframe 
    id = "pmap" width="600" height="450" 
    src = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=25.6552912,88.6423475&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed">
   </iframe>
```

Comment: you are not returning anything from the function. and where are you calling the function?

Comment: The function is called on click a button. Then it also connects the URL but says Google refused to connect. if lin equal to a simple Wikipedia page, then it's working. but not same for Google Map.

Comment: Try: `lin = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + lat + "," + long + "&hl=es;z=14&output=embed";`